# How to remove hover effect from CSS?

Tags: html, css, class

I'm currently having a text as hyperlink and on this some CSS code is getting applied. Due to which on hover the text got underline and font gets bold on hover event. But now what I want to do is remove the hyperlink and apply the same effect bydefault i.e. not on hover. In short I want to apply the style currently applying on hover without hovering the text. My HTML and css code is as follows:

```
.faq .section p.quetn a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-weight:bold
}
<p class="quetn"><a href="">5.14 Where do i see my test results?</a></p>
```

One more important thig is I can't change the above written CSS, I want to override the above CSS code by writing a new class. Can you help me in achieving this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use the same rule for when the link is not being hovered:

```
.faq .section p.quetn a, .faq .section p.quetn a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-weight:bold
}
```

**EDIT**

Juse seen that you can't change the CSS for some reason.

Just create a new class with the same styles.

```
a.class, a.class:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-weight:bold
}

<a class="class" title="" href="#">Some Link</a>
```

**EDIT v2**

Do you want to style the text but remove the link markup?

It would just be

```
<p class="class">Text</p>

p.class {
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-weight:bold
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then instead using

```
.faq .section p.quetn a:hover
```

use

```
.faq .section p.quetn a
```

If you are targeting only P tag instead of anchor tag, then use it as below :

```
.faq .section p.quetn
```

Comment: :But I want to remove the anchor tag(hyperlink) too. then how should i write as above?

Comment: in that case just use `.faq .section p.quetn` and remove A tag from html

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TmB49/)**

**css**

```
.quetn a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<p class="quetn newClass"><a href="">5.14 Where do i see my test results?</a></p>
```

**css**

```
.quetn a:hover {
        text-decoration:underline;
        font-weight:bold;
        cursor:default;
}

.newclass a:hover{
        text-decoration:none; !important
        font-weight:bold; !important
        cursor:default; !important
}
```

Use !important for priority.

Answer (score 0):

Code below for Hover Enable

```
a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Code below for Hover Disable

```
a:nohover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```